# Unable to display multiple captures from same group of each line in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

So the powershell script works accurately if the regex matches only one entry each line in the masterfile, but if more than one entry matches in each line the output is not what is expected. I am using this:-

```
$FILE_RE = '^[^\:]*[^\.txt:]'
$TEXT_RE = '"(.*?)"'
$TEXT = (Get-Content .\masterfile.txt).ToUpper() |
                ForEach-Object { 
                    New-Object psobject -Property @{
                        fileName = [regex]::Matches($_, $FILE_RE).Value
                        Value = [regex]::Matches($_, $TEXT_RE).value 
                    }
                }
         $TEXT | Select-Object  fileName , Value |  Sort-Object * -Unique |
         Export-Csv   TEXT.CSV -NoTypeInformation`
```

The data of the file and corresponding regex [can be found here.](https://regex101.com/r/Ip9RBW/3)
The output in Value tab consist **System.Object[]** which has 2 values. How i can have all the entries displayed which are inside **System.Object[]** with its corresponding file name in the first column.
The intended output is:-

```
fileName    Value
FILE1.TXT   VALUE1
FILE1.TXT   VALUE2
FILE2.TXT   VALUE3
FILE2.TXT   TEST STRING1
FILE3.TXT   VALUE4
FILE3.TXT   3456789
FILE4.TXT   VALUE5
FILE4.TXT   TEXT1
FILE5.TXT   VALUE6
FILE5.TXT   LOREM IPSUM
FILE6.TXT   VALUE7
```

Comment: You should show your expected result. IMO you need  a better single RegEx.

Comment: @LotPings updated with intended output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are several finds of $TEXT_RE per line you need to store the file and iterate the finds.

- Removed the intermediate $Text
- had to trim the surrounding `"`  from value

---

```
$FILE_RE = '^[^:]+'
$TEXT_RE = '"([^ ].+?)"'
(Get-Content .\masterfile.txt).ToUpper() | ForEach-Object {
    $File = [regex]::Matches($_, $FILE_RE).Value
    ForEach ($Value in ([regex]::Matches($_, $TEXT_RE).value)) {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            fileName = $File
            Value    = $Value.Trim('"')
        }
    }
} | Select-Object  fileName , Value |  Sort-Object * -Unique |
    Export-Csv .\TEXT.CSV -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv .\TEXT.CSV
```

Sample Output:

```
fileName  Value
--------  -----
FILE1.TXT VALUE1
FILE1.TXT VALUE2
FILE2.TXT TEST STRING1
FILE2.TXT VALUE3
FILE3.TXT 3456789
FILE3.TXT VALUE4
FILE4.TXT TEXT1
FILE4.TXT VALUE5
FILE5.TXT LOREM IPSUM
FILE5.TXT VALUE6
FILE6.TXT VALUE7
```